# MVVM: Make Binding update ViewModel only when data is VALID

Tags: wpf, validation, mvvm, idataerrorinfo, cinch

I have a ViewModel that implements the IDataErrorInfo interface. It just has a property: MyNumber.

In my view have a TextBox in which the user can type any number, but **only numbers from 0 to 9 are valid.**

So far, the textbox is marked in red when the validation fails, but I have a problem: this doesn't avoid the bound property in the ViewModel to be set.

In few words, the MyNumber property is set no matter the input is valid or not. I don't want the MyNumber gets invalid data.

How could achieve this in a pure MVVM approach?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Basically, you can't. And you shouldn't want to, because that's not how it is supposed to be implemented. If `MyNumber` wouldn't be set, how would you know that it had been set with an invalid value? You would have no value to check against, so your `IDataErrorInfo` implementation wouldn't work.

Comment: That's a good point. Well, the real use case is that I have that the MyNumber property also represents the BorderThickness of a graphic. I don't what that border to be more than 5 pixels in size, for example. The user can type 100 and the text input shows the error, but since the MyNumber property really gets that 100, the border grows to 100, breaking my rule.

Comment: I have thought of setting a Style DataTrigger that checks whether the value is valid or not and sets the binding accordingly, but I didn't know if that's OK. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: In that case, it might be good to have two properties: `DesiredWidth` (bound to the textbox) and `Width` (bound to the border). Set `Width` from within `DesiredWidth` only if it is valid.

Comment: And if you add a `DataTrigger` to a property `IDataErrorInfo Error string`? If he return error string, then not assign a value.

Comment: i'm right that you write your MyNumber with binding in a TExtBox and you read MyNumber with binding for your border? if you want a range to fit simply use a converter for that "read-binding"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time researching, I've come to a very satisfying solution:

Since I'm using the [Cinch MVVM Framework by Sacha Barber](http://cinch.codeplex.com/), the properties in my ViewModel that require validation use a very handy class that is called DataWrapper. It wraps the actual property and provides some useful features. In fact, the MyProperty I mentioned before is a DataWrapper. I added to its "Rules" collection the desired rule "x <= 5".

A very good thing about the DataWrapper class is that is contains a property called "IsValid" that indicates whether the actual value breaks the rules you have set to it.

*This encapsulates in the wrapper all the properties I need to check for validation!*

The next step is set up a Binding in the XAML to the DataWrapper, but I decided the Binding **will only apply** when the DataWrapper contains a VALID value.

**WARNING. complex explanation ahead.**

You can ask me why I need this behavior. It's a bit complex. The view is like a wizard in which the user can choose sizes, colors and other graphic aspects of the model. The model is represented in the View using a Control. To simplify the understanding (it's a bit more complex than this) you can assume that the model is **a class called Portrait** and it will be represented in the View with a **Border** control. The TextBox in which the user enters the thickness of the Portrait has a Binding  to a property in the ViewModel (the aforementioned DataWrapper), that I will call "BorderThicknessWrapper". In fact, the Binding is set to BorderThicknessWraper.DataValue, so typing into the TextBox modifies the actual value of the data held in the DataWrapper.

With that, we have the value that the user enters in the TextBox in the ViewModel.

Now we want to make the control that represents the model to reflect the changes. We said we will have a Border as the representation of our Portrait, so every change the the BorderThicknessWrapper will modify the BorderThickness of the Border. But wait, we DO WANT it to represent valid values so in the XAML I have this! Magical trick ;)

```
<Border>
  <Border.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding BorderThickessWrapper.IsValid}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{Binding GutterWidth.DataValue}" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Border.Style>
```

As you can see, the Border has a Style with a DataTrigger that states "when the wrapper has a valid value, set the binding". When the property is not valid, the default value is applied.

What we need so far!

I hope you understand the solution. It's pure MVVM based :D and pretty SOLID!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you're going about this the wrong way.

If you want to restrict input to numbers only, don't use a standard text box. Instead use a control that restrict what input / format is valid, such as IntegerUpDown /  DecimalUpDown / DoubleUpDown from the WPF Control Toolkit - available via Nuget. You can then bind the value of this control to a field of the appropriate numeric type in the view model.

Comment: Since you are right with that point of view when it comes to numeric values (it's a good solution to the problem), if you have some other values that are strings, Colors, or other types, I'm more comfortable with the ViewModel being responsible of validation. It feels way more elegant than binding max / min values to properties in the ViewModel. Anyways I voted up to you :)

Comment: In general, I would say don't allow free format text entry for data you have to validate in that way. So for example, for a color value, either give the user a pick list of pre-defined colors values or provide a color picker control that only allows valid values to be returned to the ViewModel. Similarly for dates etc.